# Mavericks: Capybara Firefox and Chrome crashes with "Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart" error

Tags: rspec, capybara, bitnami

When running Rspec using Capybara I keep getting this error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: __cg_jpeg_resync_to_restart
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  Expected in: /Applications/rubystack-2.0.0-12/*/libJPEG.dylib
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
```

I'm running under **RubyStack 2.0.0-12**, and have been trying to link the libraries from Mac OS X itself without luck.

If I run `/Applications/rubystack-2.0.0-12/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.1.0/bin/webkit_server` or `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin` manually under the RubyStack `rubyconsole`, they start up just fine, but as soon as I use Rspec to run the browsers they crash.

Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson learned, **don't use RubyStack** or other one click installers. Just use RVM and how it is meant to be. It is working just fine after I decided to just go for system ruby.